# How to read resistive buttons with Arduino Pro Micro?

Tags: button, arduino-pro-micro

I am trying to read some resistive buttons presses on a PCB like this:

[image: game gear buttons PCB]

This is the full sketch I am using:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

byte ZbuttonPin = 3; 

void setup() {
 // initialize the button-reading pins
  pinMode(ZbuttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(ZbuttonPin) == 0) {
    // if the button goes low
    Keyboard.write('z'); // send a 'z' to the computer via Keyboard HID
    delay(100); // delay so there aren't a kajillion z's
  }
}
```

If I short the Arduino pin 3 and GND directly it outputs the "z" letter correctly.

But when I connect M16 and GND on the PCB it outputs "z" continuously even if the button if not pressed with the rubber pad.

Comment: I would suppose that showing the circuit would help others help you. Shorting this or shorting may mean a lot to you hurt exactly zero to those who may be of help to you. Help others help you.

Comment: Use a multimeter to test the resistance when the button is pressed and when it is not pressed. Perhaps adjusting the voltage level with a pullup resistor is enough to make it work.

Comment: the resistance is about 1.5M ohms when not pressed and 170ohms when pressed... should i change the read logic?

Comment: Those values seem okay. It should work. Perhaps you can try with an extra pullup resistor of about 1k to 10k from pin 3 to 5V.

Comment: i've tried adding a 10K resistor in series with the pin 3, but still not working as expected. do you think [using the 5v pin and wiring like this may solve the problem](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/KeyboardMessage)?

Comment: The button at GND and the pullup at 5V or vice versa, that is the same for an Arduino Uno, and almost the same for an Arduino Pro Micro. The Arduino Pro Micro has lower voltage levels for HIGH and LOW for a digital input. You can get the same result by adjusting the value of the pullup resistor. Do you have more resistors to try ? Do you use a breadboard or something else with bad contacts ? If nothing works, you could try an analog input and check at which analog value a pressed button is.

Comment: I am using crocodile clips and no breadboard. I've also tried connecting to a momentary pushbutton and it worked fine. Probably i am going to try with analogRead and see what happens...